# How to restyle C code to exclude assignments from if statement conditions

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, coding-style, kernel

I am leaning to code via Linux kernel hacking, doing mostly janitorial patches. recently I came across some unusual if statements that contained a variable assignment inside of the conditional portion of the statement.

```
if (!strcmp(filename, "-"))
    cpio_list = stdin;
else if (!(cpio_list = fopen(filename,"r"))) { 
    ...
    ...
}
```

checkpatch.pl is calling it a style error. in what way would I (could I?) restructure this code without breaking it?

file: `linux/usr/gen_init_cpio.c`

Comment: "*some unusual if statements*" it's not so unusual, but quiet common.

Comment: `fopen` is generally not in kernel code, but in application code!

Comment: It looks like you want to use [coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) which is a tool designed to find such code patterns

Comment: @alk Quite common, quite ugly, quite bad programming practice. In other words, quite Linux kernel :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the `else if` so you can do the assignment before the `if`.

```
if (!strcmp(filename, "-"))
    cpio_list = stdin;
else {
        cpio_list = fopen(filename,"r")
        if (!cpio_list) { 
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

But you might want to refactor out a function so that you can just `return` before the `else`.

Personally, I don't think it's a big deal to have an occasional assignment-in-if-condition as long as it is parenthesized (which means the programmer meant it, it stands out as obvious, and suppresses compiler warnings).

Answer (score 1):

Assignment expressions have values. Its value is the value of its left operand after the assignment.

So  `cpio_list = fopen(filename,"r")` is valid to be used in expressions, specifically as conditions.

Some people thinks this would make the code less readable, and prefers to test explicitly:

```
else if ((cpio_list = fopen(filename,"r")) != 0)
```

Note that the parenthesis are necessary because `=` has a lower precedence than `==` and `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!strcmp(filename, "-"))
    cpio_list = stdin;
else {
    cpio_list = fopen(filename,"r");
    if (! cpio_list) { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean up the code from all bad programming practice:

- Avoid assignment inside conditions as it tends to create bugs and sometimes makes the code harder to read (assignment inside conditions is banned by MISRA-C).
- Do not use boolean operators to check pointers against NULL, or to check integers against 0. It will work but it doesn't make any sense and makes the code harder to read (also banned by MISRA-C).
- Use braces after each statement to prevent accidental bugs.
- Strive to write clear, explicit, self-documenting code.

  ```
  if (strcmp(filename, "-") == 0)
  {
    cpio_list = stdin;
  }
  else 
  {
    cpio_list = fopen(filename,"r");
    if(cpio_list == NULL)
    {
       // error handling
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: i checked your code against linux kernel style using checkpatch.pl  'total: 11 errors, 2 warnings, 12 lines checked'

Comment: @jason The "linux kernel style guide" is a a very poor, amateur-level coding standard... the document lacks rationales for everything inside it and it is mostly concerned with formatting, not avoiding blatantly dangerous practices or poorly-specified behavior. If you want a professional coding standard use MISRA or CERT.